# gentoo kernel compile bzImage error -- bad register name '%dill'

Tags: gentoo

I'm installing gentoo Linux and I just installed my kernel, but has to configure.

When I compile my kernel with `make && make modules_install`, it gives me an error in the end saying:

```
arch/x86/boot/boot.h: Assembler messages:
arch/x86/boot/boot.h:122: Error: bad register name '%dill'
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/boot/video.o] Error 1
make: *** [bzImag] Error 2
```

I have tried `genkernel` and manually configuring my kernel, by both gives me the same error; I used `make menuconfig` and not `emerge genkernel`.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: how about some hardware specifications of the machine you're compiling on?

Answer (score 1):

One way or another, your compiler isn't correctly configured. Without more hardware specs, this is, I think, the best a person can do:

The Gentoo guide to optimizing (aka for a first time gentoo install: configuring,) your compiler is at http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/gcc-optimization.xml

If you need further help, post your `cat /etc/make.conf`, `cat /proc/cpuinfo`, and for good measure, then `env` output from your bash session, although your bash session's env will probably reveal nothing of value unless make.conf is fine.

PS: Be sure to run `make clean` after changing anything compiler related in make.conf, in case it finished anything and left it laying around.